# Appropriate word for "something that will kick in if something bad happens"

Tags: legalese

I'm drafting a somewhat official document, and I can't quite think of the right word here:

**All employees are covered under an occupational hazard insurance, which would *cover* any liabilities arising from A, B, or C.**

The sentence sounds kind of awkward because *cover* is used twice. Is there a more appropriate word I can use instead of the second *cover*, something like *mitigate*? (I know mitigate wouldn't be appropriate, just an example)

Comment: How about "_All employees are **protected** by an occupational hazard insurance..._" to reduce the use of _cover_ and add a bit more agency/proactiveness.

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco That works. I'm getting this nagging feeling that there exists a word that would be a very natural fit for the second 'cover', but I might be entirely wrong. I'll wait to see if someone can recall that magic word, otherwise I'll go with protected.

Comment: **Cover** is a good choice, because that's what insurance does.

Comment: I agree with @JohnGo-Soco’s comment: the second use of *cover* works well. If you want to change one instance, consider changing the first. But with legal terminology involved, tread carefully.

Comment: @Lawrence I see, that makes sense. The legal implications of the wording aren't a big concern, it's only a semi-official document and not something a lawyer should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the second *cover*, I suggest the following:

> All employees are covered under an occupational hazard insurance, which would **apply to** any liabilities arising from A, B, or C.

However, I can't speak to any required legal terminology.

---

As another note, I find the use of *would* to be strange—even in the original version. Surely it's true that it *does* (cover or apply to) A, B, or C. Not just that it *would*.

In that sense, I suggest a further change beyond the original scope of your question:

> All employees are covered under an occupational hazard insurance, which applies to any liabilities arising from A, B, or C.

Comment: Thanks for the input on the 'would'. The actual sentence in my document is a question: "I request information on: a. Whether all employees are covered under an insurance, which would apply to liabilities arising from A, B, or C". I feel that in this construction "would" is more appropriate, thoughts?

Comment: @AnkushJain The *would* makes more sense in that context.

Answer (score 1):

[Cater to](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cater%20to) can be an option. It means "to provide what is wanted or needed  by someone / something".

> All employees are covered under an occupational hazard insurance, which would cater to any liabilities arising from A, B, or C.